# Serializer removing one to many relationship in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

When I try to attach photos to a pet the serializer is removing the attachment, I'm getting `attachment :['This field is required']`. My code:

models.py

```
class Pet(models.Model):
   pet_id = models.UUIDField('pet uid',default=uuid.uuid4,null=False,primary_key=True,blank=False,editable=False, unique=True)  
   name = models.CharField('Pet name', max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    attachment_id = models.UUIDField('attachment uid',default=uuid.uuid4,null=False,primary_key=True,blank=False,editable=False, unique=True)       
    pet_id = models.ForeignKey(Pet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/', null=False, blank=False)
    upload_at = models.DateTimeField('Time it was uploaded', max_length=50, null=False, blank=False )
```

serializers.py

```
class AttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = ('name','upload_at')

class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachment = AttachmentSerializer(source='attachment_set', many=True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Pet
        fields = ('pet_id','name', 'attachment')
    
    # because this: 
    # https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers
    def create(self, validated_data):
        attachments = validated_data.pop('attachment')
        pet = Pet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for att in attachments:
            Attachment.objects.create(pet_id=pet.pet_id, **att)
        return pet
```

views.py

```
def create_pet(self, request):      
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)         
    if not serializer.is_valid():
       return Response({'error':serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    serializer.save()

    return Response({'data':serializer.validated_data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

if on `PetSerializer` I do `attachment = AttachmentSerializer(many=True, source='attachment_set', required=False)` there is no problem with the attachment but I need the attachments.

Also I have done in the models.py on the `Attachment`
`pet_id = models.ForeignKey(Pet, related_name='attachments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and the serializers `PetSerializer`:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Pet
        fields = ('pet_id','name', 'attachments')

    # because this: 
    # https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers
    def create(self, validated_data):
        attachments = validated_data.pop('attachment')
        pet = Pet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for att in attachments:
            Attachment.objects.create(pet_id=pet.pet_id, **att)
        return pet
```

but I get the same error.
Besides I have check the contents of `request.data` and the attachment is there.

Any thoughts about this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, on the serializer change this `attachment = AttachmentSerializer(source='attachment_set', many=True)` to `attachment = serializers.ListField(child=AttachmentSerializer(many=True))` and adding in the create method `attachments = attachments[0]`. Updating the code:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachment = serializers.ListField(child=AttachmentSerializer(many=True))
    class Meta: 
        model = Pet
        fields = ('pet_id','name', 'attachment')
    
    # because this: 
    # https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers
    def create(self, validated_data):
        attachments = validated_data.pop('attachment')
        pet = Pet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        attachments = attachments[0] # Extract the list inside the list
        for att in attachments:
            Attachment.objects.create(pet_id=pet.pet_id, **att)
        return pet
```